# How to implement custom drop-down menu to actionbar in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, android-actionbar

i am trying to implement drop down menus in in actionbar, ( the count of items may very in runtime). for eg: Google map has the one.

how to implement it in android. here how the menu i'm looking for. i.e if i click on R image button i want a a drop down menu. similarly if i tap on L, left side menu should come. any idea how to do? .

I dont want sliding at all, i want a dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the action bar's structure, you have two options for the left side and one for the right side.

#### Left side:

Enable [Action bar drop-down navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown)

```
 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

*or*

Add a custom `View` as navigational element via [`ActionBar#setCustomView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int)), a `Spinner` in your case.

#### Right side:

Add only one `MenuItem` to the action bar as a [custom Action View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView), a `Spinner` in your case.

Comment: Hi, Matthias, thanks for your reply any sample examples available for how to add custom action view in android for Actionbarsherlock ? pls provide me if you have so

Comment: Yes, take a look at the ActionBarSherlock sample app: [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos) and [Code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos)

Comment: Ok, i will check it, if i have any problem i will ask you. thanks lot

Answer (score 1):

The drop-down menu on the right side of the action bar is an old navigation design so they replace it with the new [Backdrop](https://material.io/components/backdrop) material component.

[image: behavior of backdrop]

---

The old solution is

```
 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

> This [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar#setNavigationMode(int)) was deprecated in API level 21.
> Action bar navigation modes are deprecated and not supported by inline toolbar action bars. Consider using other [common navigation patterns](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph) instead.